# iOS - Multiple layers making animation slow

Tags: ios, performance, animation, calayer

I have a subview with many CAShapeLayers I animate, and this make the animation to be slow. Besides that, the animations should be executed sequentially, but I don't know why, they are executed almost at the same time. Is there something I could change to address these things? (I'm using animateWithDuration).

Snippet:

```
for (id layer in self.layer.sublayers) {
...
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f
                         delay:0.0f 
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                                subLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(subLayer.affineTransform, 1.5, 1.5);
                                 [subLayer setZPosition:1000];    
                                 }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                                              delay:1.5f 
                                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                         animations:^{ subLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                         }
                                         completion:nil
                                      ];

                                 }];
...
}
```

---

I've changed the way I animate, but still, it is not smooth:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                        selector:@selector(newCicle) 
                                                                          object:nil];
[queue addOperation:operation];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

int layerNumber = 1;
for (id layer in self.layer.sublayers) {
    if ([layer isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]]) {
        int k = layerNumber % SQHOR;
        int i = ceil((float)layerNumber / (float)SQHOR);
        CGColorRef color = nil;

        if (changed[i][k]) {
            if (matrix[i][k]) {
                color = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
            }
            else {
                color = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
            }

            CAShapeLayer *subLayer = (CAShapeLayer*)layer;                                             

            subLayer.fillColor = color;

        }
        layerNumber++;
    }

}

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Can you paste some code snippets? :)

Answer (score 1):

If the animations should be executed sequentially,  computing your every animation delay time, it's should be like this:

```
CGFloat everySubLayerAnimationDuration = 1.5f; // or other 
for (int i = 0; i < sublayers.count; i++)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration: everySubLayerAnimationDuration * i
                     delay:0.0f  
    ......
}
```

Comment: Actually the animations should occur all at once, but besides the pre-processing time, there are like 1500 layers to animate. What should I do?

Comment: Animation of 1500 layers is never ever going to be smooth. The iPhone/iPad CPU/GPU is not capable of animating that amount of layers. Redesign your app to use (a lot) less layers.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `setShouldRasterize:YES` to your layers OR your superlayer.

Comment: This just decreased the animation quality, but not its speedy.

Comment: I've updated the way I animate, but even using threads to perform the pre-processing, the animation still is not smooth.